# nuxt3 2回fetchしても１回しかリクエストを飛ばさない

Tags: nuxt.js

`nuxt ver:3.0.0-rc.11`

以下の構成で、composableのfetchメソッドを呼び出すコンポーネントを作成し、
pagesで２回呼び出したところ、APIリクエストを１回しかcallしません

### tree

```
 components: composable define fetch method call
 composable: callAPI fetch typescript
 pages: view page
```

#### composable/api.ts

```
export const useAnalyze = async (body: object): Promise<string> => {
  const { data, pending, refresh, error } = await useAsyncData(
    'key-analyze',
    () =>
      $fetch('/analyze', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: body,
        async onResponse({ request, response }) {
          console.log('FETCH', request, response.status)
        }
      }),
    {
      initialCache: false
    }
  )
  console.log('RESULT', data.value, error)

  return data.value
}
```

#### components/Parts.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
   {{ props.name }}:{{ resultValue }}
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>

interface PartsProps {
  name: string
}
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<PartsProps>(), {})

const resultValue = ref('')
onMounted(async() => {
  const result = await useAnalyze(props.name)
  resultValue.value = result
})
</script>
```

#### pages/view.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
   <Parts :name='value1' />
   <Parts :name='value2' />
  </div>
</template>
```

### result

networkの情報を見たところ1回分のリクエストのみ行っています

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### log

console.log FETCH :１行出力
console.log RESULT:2行出力

２回リクエストを飛ばしてほしいのですが、こちらの解決方法を知ってる方がいればよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useAsyncData`のkeyを固定値にしてしまっているために見えます。

> **key**: a unique key to ensure that data fetching can be properly de-duplicated across requests.
> -- [useAsyncData · Nuxt Composables](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-async-data/)

とあるように、keyはそのリクエストの識別（サーバーとブラウザなと）につかわれ、多重リクエストの回避を担います。ブラウザ内で複数箇所から呼び出された場合も同様です。異なるリクエストに用いるのであれば、それぞれがユニークになるキーの設定が必要でしょう。

もっとも、今回のケースにおいてuseAsyncDataの使用が適切なのかはわかりませんが。

Comment: ご指摘のとおりkeyの問題でした。

keyを重複しないように試しにprefix+Date.now()といったタイムスタンプにしたところ２つのリクエストが送信されました。
keyをそもそも指定しないとcomposableだと一緒になるので必ず指定が必要のようですね。。

助かりました！ありがとうございます！